# CSS/RWD - Images in columns not loading correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

I've just moved a wordpress site to a live server and I'm reviewing the different screen-widths. Everything looks fine with the exception of the staff images on an ipad in portrait mode -

[image: staff images]

In development there were always four staff images but this got reduced to three just before the site was moved from localhost to live. You can see the site [here](http://www.havoccreative.com). It needs to stack with two images at the top and one below with a gap on the right. Not sure why it's cutting one image in half.

Here's the relevant code -

**html/php**

```
<div class="staff">
                            <div class="masonry">            
                                <div class="brick">  
                                        <?php if( get_field('whoweare_image1') ): ?>
                                        <img src="<?php the_field('whoweare_image1'); ?>" />
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <div class="details">     
                                        <span id="info">  
                                            <h3><?php the_field('whoweare_name1'); ?></h3>  
                                            <p><?php the_field('whoweare_text1'); ?></p>  
                                        </span> 
                                    </div>     
                                </div>

                 <!-- above code repeated for each image container -->

                            </div>
                </div>
```

**style.css**

```
.staff .masonry { 
    column-count: 3;


}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 750px)  {
     .staff .masonry {

      -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }


}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 960px) {



     .staff .masonry {

      -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `.brick` has a `display: inline-block`, but that gets overwritten by `.staff .brick` (which has a higher specificity) being `display: flex`. In your media query you can add the `display: flex` only at your largest size and that should achieve what you are looking for.